# PHP не находит переменную в функции! Как исправить?

Tags: php, html, index

index.php

```
 // Даже пробовал добавлять суда $username=null;
       <? php
        include 'functions.php';
                    poligons($_POST["username"], "empty", "username:");?>
```

---

functions.php

```
<?php
function poligons($post, $empty, $txt){
            if(isset($post)){
              $username="$txt <u>".$post."</u>";
              echo $username;}
            else {
                $username=null;
                echo "$txt $empty<br />";
              }
}?>
```

---

Начал учить PHP, написал input в html, и окна вывода этого инпута в php. И, что бы сократить код решил вывод написать в функции и через нее выводить инпут. *Ошибка в Undefined index: **username** in index.php on line 47*.

---

Весь код:
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>php</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
    <?php echo "<p>'Hello World!'</p>";
      echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
      $text_i="text"; $email="email"; $username="Name";
    ?>
    <br><br><br>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
          <div class="main_input">
            <div class="field">
              <label for="username">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label for="text_i">Text:</label>
              <input id="text_i" type="text" name="text_i" placeholder="Your text" /><br />
            </div>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" />
          </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="poli">
      <div class="poligon">
        <?php
          echo "<h2>PHP variables</h2><hr>";
          $firstString = "the First; ";
          $secondString = "the Second;";
          $result = $firstString.$secondString;
          echo $result;
         ?>
      </div>
      <div class="poligon">
          <?php
            $username=null;
            include 'functions.php';
            poligons($_POST["username"], "empty", "username:");
            // if(isset($_POST["username"])){
            //   $username="username: <u>".$_POST['username']."</u>";
            //   echo $username;}
            // else {
            //     $username=null;
            //     echo "username: empty<br />";
            //   }
            // if(isset($_POST["email"])){
            //   $email="<br>request?!WTF: <u>".$_POST['email']."</u>";
            //   echo $email;}
            // else {
            //   $email=null;
            //   echo "email: empty<br />";
            // }
          ?>
      </div>
      <div class="poligon" id="text_i_opt">
            <?php
              if (isset($_POST["text_i"])) {
                $text_i="Text: <br /><u>".$_POST['text_i']."</u>";
                echo $text_i;}
              else {
                $text_i=null;
                echo "text_i: <br /><p align=center><tr vertical-align:50%>empty</p></tr>";
              }
            ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: При начальной загрузке страницы массив `$_POST` пуст и попытка обратиться по какому-либо ключу выдаст ошибку о несуществовании оного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что содержимое массива `$_POST` появляется только после того, как PHP-скрипт получит POST-данные, после отправки их из формы. При первом обращении к форме, когда используется метод GET содержимое массива `$_POST` не заполнено. Чтобы избежать вывода этого замечания вам лучше переработать логику обработчика таким образом, чтобы он включался только если получены данные из формы

```
include 'functions.php';
if(isset($_POST["username"])) {
  poligons($_POST["username"], "empty", "username:");
}
```

В этом случае ошибка следующая ошибка

*Ошибка в Undefined index: username in index.php on line 47.*

Выводится не будет.

Comment: а не правильнее будет проверять `array_key_exists('username', $_POST)`? понятно, чо в post значение никак не будет NULL, но в других случаях можно попасться

Comment: Спасибо!
Но почему не выводится else?

Comment: @ALPHA, вообще должен выводиться, в браузере посмотрите в исходном коде - его точно нет? Возможно разметка так устроена, что значение скрыто?

Comment: И если можно, ответьте пожалуйста еще на пару вопросов: что такое => или -> (в коде php на разных сайтах видел как одни переменные указывают на другие таким образом - что это?)
И как очистить значения в post (что бы при обновлении страницы он был пустой)?

Comment: @toxxxa, как вариант, но обычно, если нет надобности стремятся код сделать короче (его проще воспринимать и сложнее ошибиться). Например, часто ставят такую проверку if(!empty($_POST)), предполагая, что если POST-данные пришли, то из конкретной формы.

Comment: @cheops, нет - в браузере не выводит else о_О

Comment: @ALPHA не стесняйтесь задавать много вопросов, идеально под каждый новый вопрос - заводить новую тему. => используется в ассоциативных массивах/цикле foreach для того, чтобы сопоставить ключу значение. -> используется для обращение к методу или члену объекта в объектно-ориентированном программировании.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39803/discussion-between-alpha-and-cheops).